# Sed: replace text keeping digit occurrence

Tags: sed, regular-expression, replace, html, trim

I have some text like:

```
Blablabla <b>[intlink id="</b>2204<b>" type="page"] Blalala
```

I want replace it for remove the `</b>` and `<b>`, keeping the `id="number"`. So it should result like:

```
Blablabla <b>[intlink id="2204" type="page"] Blalala
```

I try with:

```
sed -i 's@id="</b>[[:digit:]]\+<b>"@id="{1}"@g' ~/edit.txt
Blablabla <b>[intlink id="{1}" type="page"] Blalala
```

Also I try with:

```
sed -i 's@id="</b>[[:digit:]]\+<b>"@id="\\1"@g' ~/edit.txt
```

But I get:

```
Blablabla <b>[intlink id="\1" type="page"] Blalala
```

So, how I can keep the id number text in the regex digit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\1` is the right syntax for referring to capture group 1; `\\1` means you want the literal text `\1`. So change `\\1` to `\1`, and then you need to put parentheses around the part you actually want to capture. This should work:

```
sed -i 's@id="</b>\([[:digit:]]\+\)<b>"@id="\1"@g' ~/edit.txt
```

Comment: It is not working with \1, it replaces to id="1" and not keeping the digit (I put the parenthesis too, not working), what could be the issue? I am running in bash

Comment: @shakaran Te brackets were wrong set. The `\(\)` groupding includes now the whole number.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. I accidentally left the `+` outside of the parentheses